# how to bind jquery change event to dynamic tables/rows?

Tags: php, jquery

In PHP, I have a dynamic number of tables, and each table has a dynamic number of rows.  The last column in the table ($reasonstr) is a drop down list.  I want to capture the change in that drop down.  If I do this:

```
                    $('#reason2td3').change(
                     function(){
                        }
```

I'm able to capture what I need.  However, I want this to be dynamic, based on the number of tables and rows on the page.

I have identified the tables & rows as follows:

table, where $id increases with each table on the page:

```
echo sprintf('<table cellspacing="0" class="myTable" id="myTable%s">',$id);
```

so, if there are two tables on the page, they are #myTable1 and #myTable2.

rows, where $tdid increases with each row in the table:

```
                     echo '<tbody>';
                   foreach ($record as $r) {
                        echo sprintf('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>$ %s</td><td>%s</td><td id="reason%std%s">%s</td></tr>',
                             $r['org_number'],
                             $r['dept_descr'],
                             $r['supplier_number'],
                             $r['supplier_name'],
                             $r['invoice_number'],
                             $r['receive_date'],
                             $r['final_qty'],
                             number_format($r['final_cost'],2),
                             $r['inv_status'],
                                $id,
                                $tdid,
                                $reasonstr);
                             $tdid++;
                   }
                  echo '</tbody></table>';
                  $tdid=0;
```

so, the 3rd row in table 2 is #reason2td3.

How do I capture the $id and $tdid from PHP and use it in JQuery?

Comment: to dinamically capture use `$(document).on("change",'#reason2td3',function(){...})`, to capture $id $tdid you must assign them to some attribute or pass them to javascript function.

Comment: @mwebber Delegation is not the issue here, since the page is built using php.  The tables aren't added after the DOM has been constructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) :

```
$('[id^="myTable"]').on('change', function(){
   var $id   = this.id;
   // do stuff
});
```

That will target all elements with an ID starting with myTable, for instance `myTable1`, `myTable2`, `myTableStackOverflowChineseOldMan` etc.

Inserting the elements with PHP doesn't really make them dynamic, so delegated event handlers shouldn't be needed for this.